# Trying to create a multiplication table, the for loop won’t work for some numbers

Tags: javascript

so I’m trying to code a program which takes two numbers as input, and prints a multiplication table between those two numbers (ex- if we entered 2 and 6, it will print tables for 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6). So far the code works, but not for all inputs, on entering 2 and 10, I get no output, same with any number from 2-9 as the first input, and 10 as the second one, the code won’t work, any help would be really appreciated!

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('submit-btn');
let outer = document.querySelector('#table-data');
let titleTable = document.getElementById('title-table');

let firstNumber;
let secondNumber;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  firstNumber = document.getElementById('numberFirst').value;
  secondNumber = document.getElementById('numberSecond').value;

  printTable(firstNumber, secondNumber);
  titleTable.innerHTML = "";

  titleTable.innerHTML += `Table for the numbers between ${firstNumber} and ${secondNumber}`

})


// Function to print the table

function printTable(x, y) {
  outer.innerHTML = "";
  for (i = x; i <= y; i++) {

    outer.innerHTML += `<b> Table of ${i} <br> </b>`
    for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
      outer.innerHTML += `${i} &#215; ${j} = ${i*j} <br>`;

      console.log(`${i} * ${j} = ${i*j}`)
    }

    outer.innerHTML += "<br>"

  }

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-fields {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
}

.output-area {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 85%;
  background: gray;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-fields">
  <label for="no1">
                <span>Enter first number :</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input id="numberFirst" type="text" required>
        </label>

  <label for="no2">
                <span>Enter second number :</span>
                <input id="numberSecond" type="text" required>
        </label>

  <button id="submit-btn" type="submit">Generate tables</button>

</div>

<div class="output-area">
  <h2 id="title-table"> </h2>
  <span id="table-data"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you wish to handle negative numbers like -2, -3?  Do you wish to limit the range i.e. not allow 12342,12302 as values?  What about 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, I was getting to the value as a string, had to parse it to a number, by using Number()

```
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    //Parsing into a number
    firstNumber = Number(document.getElementById('numberFirst').value);
    secondNumber = Number(document.getElementById('numberSecond').value); 

    printTable(firstNumber,secondNumber);
    titleTable.innerHTML = "";

    titleTable.innerHTML += `Table for the numbers between ${firstNumber} and ${secondNumber}`

})
```

Comment: Does not work for values "webad3" or other text entries which this allows.

Comment: Does not work for values where first is bigger than second 3, 2 but does for 2, 3.  Also does not work for non-integer numbers like 2.1, 3

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Hi, yes I still haven't added the condition checking for those conditions, I'll add those to the code later

Comment: You should accept this answer if it gives you what you wish presently (click green check)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss It seems like I can accept the answer in two days